# Fill a Pytables array with random values: horizontally vs vertically

Tags: python, numpy, pytables

So I am using Pytables to store a numpy array of size `(10,000 x 100)`. My goal is to fill it with random values.

```
import tables as tb
h5File = '/Users/me/tmp0/test0.h5'
f = tb.openFile( h5File, 'w')
atom = tb.Atom.from_dtype( numpy.dtype('Float32'))
x = f.createCArray( f.root, 'prices', atom=atom, shape=(10000, 100) )
```

In this example I could simply do `x[:]=nr.random(10000,100)`, but in reality my matrix is much bigger, more like `(100,000,000 x 500)`. So I need to do it by chunks. First I tried vertically:

```
%%timeit
for k in xrange(100) :
    x[ :, k ] = nr.random( 10000 )

1 loops, best of 3: 255 ms per loop
```

Then I tried horizontally:

```
%%timeit
for k in xrange(0, 10000, 100) :
    x[ k:k+100, : ] = nr.random( ( 100, 100 ) )

100 loops, best of 3: 22.4 ms per loop
```

Why is the horizontal one 10 times faster? Also, is there a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the speed, its because of how computers keep memory organized.
Internally, the entire matrix is kept in linear memory.  To keep it easy to wrap our heads around: if you had a 4x4 matrix:

```
1  2
3  4
```

Internally, that would be stored as

```
memAddr1: 1
memAddr2: 2
memAddr3: 3
memAddr4: 4
```

So if you write this in rows, you get very efficient use of consecutive memory addresses (1-4).  If you write in columns, you're forcing frequent random accesses (1 then 3 then 2 then 4).

Answer (score 0):

The reason has been exposed already: the differences in how you store data in memory affects a lot to the performance you get.  For knowing more about the issue, look at the slide 19 (and neighborhoods) of this presentation:

http://www.pytables.org/docs/StarvingCPUs-PyTablesUsages.pdf